# Why aren't these two strings matching

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    str1 = str('exon_PF3DZ_0100100'.split())
    str2 = str('exon_PF3D7_0100100'.split())

    if str1 == str2:
        print 'True'
    else: print 'False'
```

then creating a new variable to store the result after  comparing the strings
    result = ''

after that trying to compare the strings using a for loop

```
for letter in str1:
 for letter in str2:
    if letter(str1) != letter(str2):
        result = result + letter
        print (result)
```

For some reason this code returns 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
if letter(str1) != letter(str2):
```

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I dont understand why the two strings do not match?

Comment: you are reusing the variable `letter` of two strings....bad practice, this is a string not a function

Comment: you're calling a function (parentheses) on a string object...

Comment: If you want to know why `str1` and `str2` do not match in your first code segment, it's because one contains a seven and one contains the letter Z. Split does nothing particularly useful (except convert the string into a list) because there is nothing in the string to split on.

Answer (score 1):

In the loops, the variable `letter` Is a *string*, containing the current character. That's the cause of your error (strings aren't functions and can't be called as such).

You also use the same variable name for both loops, the inner loop overwriting the contents of `letter` from the outer loop. You need to use two *different*  variables. That you then compare directly. Like:

```
for letter1 in str1:
    for letter2 in str2:
        if letter1 == letter2:
            # Do something here ...
```